# Calculating the Cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I’d like to lead off with saying that this is a homework problem, in case that’s something anyone might want to avoid. [Here is a link to the given information:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM1gI.jpg)

The issue that I’m having is that the pdf does not seem to be a consistent with the value I’m obtaining for $c$. In order to find the value of $c$, I took the integral of the pdf, from $-0.5$ to $0.5$, and I end up with with the integral being $2c/3$.

If I’m not mistaken, the integral of the pdf should be equal to 1, when all of the variable values are included. This being the case, $c$ would have to be $3/2$. However, if $c = 3/2$, then the pdf is $3/2 -6x^2$. Then, $f(X=0) = 3/2$.

This is where I’m currently at, and I’m trying to resolve places that I might have messed up. Is my integration incorrect? Or is my conceptual approach missing something? Alternatively, is this problem solvable? Assuming that I’ve done the above correctly, is there a way to manipulate the pdf/cdf to be correct? Any scaling or other methods to make it work?

Any and all help is appreciated!!

Comment: Why do you think your results are incorrect?

Comment: Obtaining $f(0)=3/2$ is fine, but it does not mean that $P(X=0)=3/2$. It is a continuous distribution, so at any particular point $P(X=x)=0$.

Comment: Your integration is correct. PDF can takes values greater than $1$. This is not a probability. To find CDF you need calculate $F(z)=\int_{-\infty}^z f(x)\,dx$ for all values $z$. Really there are three intervals of $z$ which should be considered separately: for $z <-\frac12$ CDF $F(z)=0$, for $-\frac12\leq z<\frac12$ 
$$F(z)=\int_{-\frac12}^z \frac32-6x^2 \,dx $$ and $F(z)=1$ for $z\geq \frac12$.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! So my misunderstanding was in that I thought pdf was a probability. If it’s not too much trouble, what exactly is the pdf? From the name, my next guess would be that the values are something like “weights” for each value of X?

Comment: If you want to calculate probability that r.v. $X$ takes values from some interval $(a,b)$ then you should integrate PDF over this interval. So, area under PDF over interval shows us the probability to take values from this interval. Large values of PDF correspond to large probabililties.

Comment: And that’s the cdf right? So the pdf is indicative of the probability; i.e. higher pdf values in an area suggest that the probability of getting a value in that region will be higher, but aren’t themselves probability. Does that sound right?

Comment: I think it sounds right. The pdf is a distribution, so it should be integrated over intervals, not particular values. You could calculate the probability of sampling a value within some error $x$, say by integrating the pdf on $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is the error.